# How to add a new item by clicking on a link in Calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

How I can add a link, by clicking the users will be able to open the "add a new item" pop-up window? I cannot find the URL of the entry form.

Comment: Have you created Calendar list using Visual studio ?

Answer (score 0):

When you mouse over on the calendar in a cell right down corner. the add link will be enabled for you. If you click on that add link it will open new form in SharePoint Popup page. you no need to add explicit, it is default functionality of share Point.

[image]

You can the new, display, edit form urls from this location, go to the ribbon ->Calendar tab look at the image

[image]

Comment: Hi Bolineni, it is not intuitive enough ... I want to add a link or button on the top of the calendar, so that, users will be able to open the form with a click.

Comment: means you need the new form link so that you can the link on top of the calendar. ? check the modified answer

Comment: thanks Bolineni, i did get the URL of the form and added a link to open it.

Comment: Can you vote up and select as an answer ..:)